# exponential distribution with probability about texts

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function, simulation

It is 9:00 p.m. The time until Joe receives his next text message has an
exponential distribution with mean 5 minutes.
A text has not arrived for 5 minutes. Find the probability that none will
arrive for 7 minutes.

I don't know where to start with, is it like P(X>7)? But then I don't know where to put in the 5 minutes. Please help.

Comment: I think the question is asking for $\Pr(X\gt 7|X\gt 5)$.  But the wording is unclear, it could be asking for $\Pr(X\gt 12|X\gt 5$. We do the first. By the usual formula for conditional probability, we divide $\Pr(X\gt 7\cap X\gt 5)$ by $\Pr(X\gt 5)$.  This is $\Pr(X\gt 7)/\Pr(X\gt 5)$. which is $e^{-7/5}/e^{-5/5}$, that is, $e^{-2/5}$. We have just proved a special case of the *memorylessness* of the exponential. But  if you already know about the memorylessness,  you could write $e^{-2/5}$ instantly.

Comment: I'd interpret the question as $\mathsf P(X>7|X>-5)=\mathsf P(X>7)$.  That is, *because* the distribution is memoryless, the fact that no message has arrived for the *previous* five minutes is *irrelevant* to calculating the probability that none will arrive within the *next* seven.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\mathsf P(X>7|X>-5)=\mathsf P(X>7) =\ldots$

That is, *because* an exponential distribution is **memoryless**, the fact that no message has arrived for the *previous* five minutes is *irrelevant* to calculating the probability that none will arrive within the *next* seven.

Answer (score 0):

Following Andre's interpretation, the answer is exp(-2/5) = 0.67032.
Because this in under a (simulation) tag, here is a verification in R
(for which the accuracy of the simulation happens to be a little better than expected):

`> x = rexp(10^7, 1/5);  mean(x[x>5] > 7)
[1] 0.670339`

Simulation under the alternate interpretation would have to begin at time 8:55pm.